# un-prettify JSON in bash

Tags: json, string, bash

I want to use a "prettified" `JSON` with a `bash` `cat` argument. Due to its used with another function I need to have it "un-prettified" (all white spaces and linebreaks removed). Is there a simple way to do it?

To give you a simple example its like this:

### Working

*file.json*:

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}
```

*foo.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
myfunc cat file.json //..
```

### Not Working

*file.json*:

```
{  
   "name":"John",
   "age":30,
   "city":"New York"
}
```

*foo.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
myfunc cat file.json //..
```

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you just want to replace line feeds with nothing?

Comment: @JNevill would be probably a solution yes. obviously I can use `sed` for that but may there are other ways (even considering all kinds of linebreaks)?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; why can `myfunc` only handle a subset of valid JSON?

Comment: @chepner the name is a bit missleading. Its not my. Its an external function out of my responsible aka a blackbox

Comment: Then you should probably file a bug report; if it is supposed to work with JSON and can't handle whitespace, who knows what else could break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with -c parameter

`jq -c '.' file.json`

will print

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) could help you.

**file.json**

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}
```

Do:

```
cat file.json | jq -c
```

Will return:

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

Even better as @Charles Duffy comment to only spin up one process, not two:

```
jq -c < file.json
```

Comment: I'd suggest `jq -c <file.json` or `jq -c . file.json` -- that way we're only spinning up one process, not two, and giving `jq` a handle on the real file, vs a handle on a FIFO connected to a program that's reading the real file; no point to that indirection when it doesn't serve a purpose.